# How to programmatically set margin for a shape in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls

margin is of type thickness so It seems I cannot do:

```
Double myMargin = 10.2;
ellipse1.margin = Math.Round(myMargin  / 2,0);
```

So what's the syntax ?

**Update:** I need same margin for top left right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) is defined as a [Thickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) structure.  You need to set the value to a new `Thickness` structure instead of a single value.

You can do:

```
double myMargin = 10.2;
myMargin = Math.Round(myMargin/2, 0);
ellipse1.Margin = new Thickness(myMargin);
```

---

Edit: If you want to have the thickness be different on the bottom (ie: this margin only on top, left, right), use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587975.aspx) instead:

```
double myMargin = 10.2;
myMargin = Math.Round(myMargin/2, 0);
ellipse1.Margin = new Thickness(myMargin, myMargin, myMargin, 0.0);
```

Comment: The code I pasted will use the constructor for thickness which takes 1 double, which gives you the same margin for all four sides.  If you want just three, I'll edit:

Comment: @user310291: I just edited to show you how to setup different thickness values for each side.  In this case, top/left/right will all be your value, and bottom will be 0.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
ellipse1.margin = new Thickness(Math.Round(myMargin / 2, 0));
```